# Must an abstract $C^*$-algebra that is an integral domain be a field?

Tags: c-star-algebras, maximal-and-prime-ideals, division-ring, gelfand-representation

I'd like to understand a little bit better why the maximal (as opposed to *prime*) spectrum is the appropriate notion of spectrum for the theory of $C^*$-algebras.

The canonical answer is that $C^*$-algebras have no non-maximal prime ideals: every $C^*$-algebra integral domain is a division ring.  In the commutative case, this is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2847393/integral-domain-and-c-algebra) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184909/characterisation-of-a-commutative-c-algebra-which-is-an-integral-domain), but both answers use the Gelfand transform in an essential way.  But I'm trying to use that fact to *motivate* the Gelfand transform in my notes, so this seems a little circular.

**Is there an abstract, "algebraic" proof that every $C^*$ integral domain is a division ring?**

Some notes:

1. In general, the class of rings for which maximal spectra suffice to characterize the topology of the prime spectrum is known as [Gelfand rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_ring).  But I don't know how to prove that a Gelfand integral domain is a field, or even that a $C^*$-algebra is Gelfand (!!).   (I'm about to ask those questions on MSE too, and will link them when I do.)
2. My guess is that one should try to mimic the proof that every finite integral domain is a field.  Note that $m_a=(x\mapsto ax)$ is a injective linear operator on $A$.  Showing that $m_a$ is surjective should be possible by some Fredholm theory, whence the claim.

Answer (score 1):

No; as written, your statement is false.  The correct statement is:

> A prime ideal of a $C^*$-algebra is maximal iff it is closed.

In particular, call a $x\in A$ an *approximate divisor of $0$* if there exists $\{y_n\}_n$ such that no $y_n=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}{xy_n}=0$.  It is straightforward to see that a prime ideal $P\subseteq A$ is closed iff $A/P$ lacks approximate divisors of $0$.  But then [a theorem of Kaplansky](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.dmj/1077475665) (proof below) states that any normed Banach algebra without approximate divisors of $0$ is a division ring.

**Kaplansky's proof (in the $C^*$ case)**

First, note that we can in fact prove more: the [Gelfand-Mazur theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Mazur_theorem) states that the only normed division algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ are $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, and $\mathbb{H}$.  $C^*$ algebras are already over $\mathbb{C}$, so we can rule out $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{H}$.  Thus it suffices to give a proof that $A\cong\mathbb{C}$.

Fix $x\in A$.  $\mathrm{Spec}{(x)}$ is compact and nonempty, so there exists $a+bi\in\partial\mathrm{Spec}{(x)}$.  Swapping $x-(a+bi)$ for $x$, we may assume $a+bi=0$ w/oLoG.

$x$ is not invertible, whilst a limit of invertible elements — say, $\{u_n\}_n$.  If $\{u_n^{-1}\}_n$ were bounded, then $xu_n^{-1}-1=(x-u_n)u_n^{-1}\to0$.  Passing to a weak-*-convergent subsequence of $\{u_n^{-1}\}_n$, we would find an (impossible) inverse of $x$.

Thus $\{u_n^{-1}\}$ is not bounded, and (by passing to a subsequence) increasing in norm.  But $\frac{u_n^{-1}}{\|u_n^{-1}\|}$ is still bounded, so $$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}{(x-u_n)\left(\frac{u_n^{-1}}{\|u_n^{-1}\|}\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{xu_n^{-1}+1}{\|u_n^{-1}\|}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{x\cdot\frac{u_n^{-1}}{\|u_n^{-1}\|}}$$  That is, $x$ is an approximate divisor of $0$.

But $A$ lacks approximate divisors of $0$.  So $x=0\in\mathbb{C}$, whence the claim.

Comment: $\{0\}$ is a closed, prime ideal of the Toeplitz algebra but it is not maximal.

Comment: Could you elaborate why for a closed prime ideal $P\subseteq A$, the quotient $A/P$ lacks approximate divisors of zero?